# Best Scheme to parse K,V data with prefix

Tags: java, parsing, nosql

I am using java to parse below mention data stream. What i am currently doing is reading line by line and parse and populate objects from Key and value under kv tag.

Below are some of the data i am parsing, each record is enclosed with "kv" keyword, and key with value "prefix" specify that all the upcoming keys should be prefixed by "CURRENT" prefix until new kv value arrives with different prefix value in it.

```
kv {
  key "prefix"
  str_value "prefix1"
}
kv {
  key "init"              //Actually it is prefix1:init
  int_value 1        
}
kv {
  key "index"             //Actually it is prefix1:index
  int_value 3
}
kv {
  key "prefix"
  str_value "prefix2"
}
kv {
  key "init"          //Actually key is prefix2:init
  int_value 1
}
kv {
  key "index"        //Actually key is prefix2:index
  int_value 6
}
kv {
  key "name"
  int_value 7
}
kv {
  key "prefix"
  str_value "prefix3/"
}
kv {
  key "index"
  int_value 8
}
kv {
  key "prefix"
  str_value "prefix1"
}
kv {
  key "index"
  int_value 7
}
```

I am wondering is there any better way of processing such data, and populate K,V pairs in Java object that can be persisted into noSQL D.B. like Redis?

Comment: Is this an actual representation of the data you're receiving or is it valid json? If it's valid json, you could use something like jackson to parse the data to objects.

Comment: This is exactly what i am getting. And data structure will always be the same. Means Kv "keyword" then curly braces having two fields init as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a scanner with useDelimiter option. I have added a sample code, which assumes the record contents are in file inputt.txt .

**DATA**

```
            kv {
          key "prefix"
          str_value "prefix1"
        }
        kv {
          key "init"
          int_value 1        
        }
        kv {
          key "index"
          int_value 3
        }
        kv {
          key "prefix"
          str_value "prefix2"
        }
        kv {
          key "init"   
          int_value 1
        }
        kv {
          key "index"   
          int_value 6
        }
        kv {
          key "name"
          int_value 7
        }
        kv {
          key "prefix"
          str_value "prefix3/"
        }
        kv {
          key "index"
          int_value 8
        }
        kv {
          key "prefix"
          str_value "prefix1"
        }
        kv {
          key "index"
          int_value 7
        }
```

**CODE**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String file = "inputt.txt";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(file)).useDelimiter("\\s+");
    /** One segment of record as parsed by scanner.
    TOKENS                  Index
    kv                      0
    {                       1
    key                     2
    "prefix"                3
    str_value               4
    "prefix1"               5
    }                       6
    */
    int tokenCount=0;
    int index1=3; 
    int index2=5;
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
       String str=scan.next();
       if(tokenCount%7==index1){
           System.out.print(str);
       }   
       if(tokenCount%7==index2){
           System.out.println("  "+str);
       }
       tokenCount++;
    }
    scan.close();
 }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
"prefix"  "prefix1"
"init"  1
"index"  3
"prefix"  "prefix2"
"init"  1
"index"  6
"name"  7
"prefix"  "prefix3/"
"index"  8
"prefix"  "prefix1"
"index"  7
```

Comment: how to avoid when we get data like -->  kv {
   str_value "prefix2"
} You can see here one of the field value is missing, we want to skip that record but that will impact rest of the records.

Comment: You can get Key or Value. By using the right index in the formula tokenCount%7==index1 . I have altered the code to print the value as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think one common way is to use regular expression in java to scan the whole string and use group to fetch these data.